# Derivative operator on the space generated by two functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, trigonometry

From Serge Lang Linear Algebra:

> Let $V$ be the space generated over $\mathbb{R}$ by the two functions $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$.
> Does the derivative (viewed as a linear map of $V$ into itself) have any
> non-zero eigenvectors in $V$? If so, which?

Initially, I thought that $V$ was a $2$-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ which contained $1$-dimensional subspace generated by $\beta =\{(\sin(t), \cos(t))\}$ (even though $\beta$ is not a maximal set in $\mathbb{R^2}$, thus not a basis set).

In that case, I think it would make sense if the matrix associated with the derivative operator $D: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ with respect to the generating set $\beta$ was:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

satisfying the equation $A(\sin(t), \cos(t))=(\cos(t), -\sin(t))$.

And then it would be directly seen from the charasteristic polynomial $\det(\lambda I-A)=t^2+1=0 \,$ that there are only complex eigenvalues for $A$, implying that $Av=\lambda v \implies \lambda = 0$ since the derivative operator defined by author is an endomorphism of real vector space.

**Problem**:

In order to verify the validity of this proof, I had to refer to the proof of this exercise in "Solutions Manual for Lang’s Linear Algebra" by Rami Shakarchi:

> *SOLUTION.* The matrix of the derivative with respect to $\{\sin t, \cos t\}$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\  1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> so the characteristic polynomial, which is $P_D(t) = t^2 + 1$, has no
> real root. Therefore, the derivative does not have a non-zero
> eigenvector. **One could also proceed directly from the definition. Let
> $v = a\cos t + b\sin t$. Then $Dv = \lambda v$ implies:**
>
> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  -a = \lambda b \\ b = \lambda a  \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> So $(\lambda^2 + 1)a = 0$, which implies that $a = b = 0$; so we see
> that $D$ does not have a non-zero eigenvector in $V$.

Everything seemed valid until the last (emphasized by bold format) part, where the author of the manual book uses another method to validate the absence of non-zero eigenvectors and defines $v$ as a linear combination of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ (with a coordinate vector $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$). This implies that the generating set $\beta$ is actually a linearly dependent set $\{\sin(t), \cos(t)\}$ instead of $\{(\sin(t), \cos(t))\}$ with a cardinality $1$.

**Question**:

Is $v=a\sin(t)+b\cos(t)$ a scalar? If so, then how is it passed to the derivative $D$ which is in the exercise defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

If $v$ is not a scalar, then are the trigonometric functions perhaps defined on $t \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Am I making a mistake somewhere in the definition of derivative or the generating set?

Comment: You have fundamentally misunderstood the question. $V$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Instead, it is a set of functions over $\Bbb R$

Comment: $\sin(t)$ is represented by the vector $(1,0)$ and $\cos(t)$ by $(0,1)$. So $D\sin t=\cos t$ becomes $A(1,0)=(0,1)$, etc.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, initially I thought that there was an error in the book which is why assumed $V$ to be a subset, since I'm having a problem understanding why is then $D$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @ShellRox If $D$ is the derivative operator, then it is not defined over $\Bbb R^2$ (or at least, we are not concerned with such a definition). Instead, we are considering the linear map $D$ over the space $V$, which is a two-dimensional space of functions. Because $V$ is two-dimensional, the **matrix of** $D$ relative to the basis $\{\sin t, \cos t\}$ is an operator over $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: @Chrystomath I think it makes sense now, so should one consider $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ as elements of $\mathbb{R^2}$? Perhaps something similar to the change of basis is happening from the standard basis $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ to the set $\{\sin t, \cos t\}$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for the clarification. How could the dimensionality of $V$ be deduced? I assume that $\beta = \{\sin(t), \cos(t)\}$ is not a basis since the two elements (as mere functions) are linearly dependent, can then the cardinality of $\beta$ still determine the dimension of $V$? I guess then $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ must be considered as elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @ShellRox The two elements are **not** linearly dependent. There are no non-zero coefficients $a,b$ for which the function defined by $g(t) = a\sin t + b \cos t$ is the zero-function.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I came up with this assumption while treating $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ as scalars, implying that coefficients for the equation would be e.g $a=1; b=-\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}$, but obviously this would not hold if the elements are not scalars. Furthermore the term "generated" instead of "spanned" in the exercise strengthened this assumption. But it makes sense that space generating set of two functions implies that two functions belong to two-dimensional space.

Comment: @Shell I don't see any difference between "generated" and "spanned" in this context. In any case, I'm glad things make sense now

Comment: @Shell I suppose that "the space generated over $\mathbb{R}$ by..." sounds like perhaps it means "the subspace of $\Bbb R$ generated by...", which could also have led to your misunderstanding.

Comment: It might be better to think of $\sin$ as a function rather than a number $\sin(t)$. $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but they are still vectors in the vector space of differentiable functions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If I recall correctly, in few occurrences author has used the term "space generated by $X$" as all linear linear combinations of $X$, not requiring $X$ to satisfy the axioms of basis for a certain space, which is why I thought $\beta$ was not linearly independent and also why I treated its elements as scalars. I guess the "space generated over $\mathbb{F}$ by $n$ functions" must be always (or at least in this case) treated as linear span of basis set of $n$ functions.

Comment: @ShellRox In that context, spanned has exactly the same connotation as generated. We can talk about the span of a set even if that set is not a basis.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I apologize, I have misused the term "spanned space" as a space that is necessarily generated from the basis set. The term "generated" without the mention of basis is what was slightly perplexing to me, and I was trying to find the indicator in the question that $\beta$ is a basis.

Comment: @Chrystomath If I may ask, could you clarify how the standard basis vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ represent $\{\sin(t), \cos(t)\}$ since they are functions? Are they just symbols or the actual vectors? Thank you!

Comment: They're the actual vectors. But instead of thinking of $(1,0)$ as representing a *geometric* point in a plane, think of it as representing a function, namely $\sin$. So $(1,0)+(0,2)$ represents $\sin+2\cos$. More precisely, the linear combinations $\alpha\sin+\beta\cos$ are represented by $(\alpha,\beta)$. This is just a representation, sort of another way of thinking about them. It is only valid if we use addition and scalar multiplication. For example, the function $\sin\times\cos$ cannot be represented this way because it is not in $V$.

Comment: @Chrystomath That's a very intuitive way of thinking about this, particularly for this problem, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @ShellRox Hey shellrox. I have a few questions in ML that I'm confused about. I know I have the corpuscles of the internet to ask but it's increasingly becoming difficult as the more questions I ask, the more questions I have. Is there a way to PM you here? I'm not gonna bother you much, I promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a two-dimensional vector $V$ space over $\mathbb{R}$, with a basis $\mathscr{B}=\{ \cos x,\sin x \}$. You can view $V$ as a subspace of real functions on $[0,2\pi]$, for example, which is a 2-dimensional subspace. The operator $D$ of differentiation is defined on $V$ by $D(\cos x)=-\sin x$ and $D(\sin x)=\cos x$. Therefore, $V$ is represented by the following $2\times 2$ matrix over  $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the basis $\mathscr{B}$:
$$
                D\sim \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$
Here $\left[\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right]$ corresponds to $a\cos x + b\sin x$, and $V(a\cos x + b\sin x)=-a\sin x + b\cos x$ is represented by the above matrix. You may perform operations on real functions, or on $\mathbb{R}^2$. $D$ has no eigenvalues because $\det(D-\lambda I)=\lambda^2+1$ has no zeros over $\mathbb{R}$. It does have zeros over $\mathbb{C}$, but that is not the context for this problem. You can shift to viewing $V$ as a subspace of real-valued functions on $[0,2\pi]$ instead of viewing $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. These are equivalent through the invertible map $(a,b)\mapsto a\cos x + b\sin x$.

Looking at the eigenvalue problem through the matrix $D$ gives the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$ which has no zeros over $\mathbb{R}$.

Looking at the eigenvalue problem in the subspace of continuous functions $a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$ in $C[0,2\pi]$ gives the problem $Df=\lambda f$ for some function $f=a\cos x + b\sin x$. That is,
$$
     -a\sin x + b\cos x = \lambda (a\cos x + b\sin x) \\
      (-a-\lambda b)\sin x + (b-\lambda a)\cos x = 0 \\
      \implies a=-\lambda b,\;\; b=\lambda a \\
      \implies a=-\lambda^2 a, \;\; b=-\lambda^2 b \\
      \implies (1+\lambda^2)a = 0 = (1+\lambda^2)b \\
       \implies a=b=0.
$$
In this context, $\cos(x),\sin(x)$ are vectors in $C[0,2\pi]$.

I think part of the confusion comes because of using the term "vector" in a "vector space" instead of a "point" in a "linear space". $\cos(x),\sin(x)$ are points in a linear space; I think that's the preferable way to describe what's going on. Vector implies pointing, and functions don't point. But functions can be points in a linear space. This terminology changed over the past 30 years, and nothing was added by making the change, except for some confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, it makes a perfect sense now. Observing the effect of the matrix $A$ as the alteration of coordinates of the functions (as elements) with respect to the basis of $V$ (e.g $[a, b]$ changing to $[b, -a]$) clears most of the confusion for me, The intuition of looking at $V$ as subspace of functions defined on certain closed interval clears a lot as well. The main misunderstanding came from looking at $[\sin(t), \cos(t)]$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$ instead of basis of function space.